# Re-open Putty Config on Connection Close

Tags: putty

I have been using putty on Windows 8.1 for some time now. There is only one problem I have with it. Is it possible to have the configuration Window open up again when a connection fails or exits without restarting the program again?(it gets annoying after a while...) I have searched through all of the settings and found no success however, I have heard that it can be done. Perhaps, I am simply missing something or maybe just crazy.

Has anyone configured this successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a connection is ended or fails (notice the "inactive" in the title bar), a new menu option appears in the window menu "Restart Session".  This will reconnect the session.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Close enough I guess...I was hoping there was a way to have Putty start a new session if connection was lost or went inactive without having to go through menus manually.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround, as there is still no real solution:

- For your connection, in the Session window, configure "Close window on exit > Never"
- In the session window, select from the menu the "New session..." menu item. This will bring back main window of putty

Comment: This is a reasonable solution. I'm just sick and tired of the Putty Config window closing on a successful connection. If I want a simultaneous connection elsewhere, I have to invoke the Putty Config again, or use your method. I'm really suprised there isn't a simple option to keep Putty Config window open at all times. Thanks for your workaround.

Answer (score 5):

[KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) is a forked version of PuTTY with more features, and it will let you keep the config window open at all times. It has the standard "Open" button that will launch a session and close the config, and also a "Start" button that will launch a session while keeping the config window open.

It also has the ability to automatically reconnect on disconnects. (Config > Connection > Reconnect Options > "Attempt to reconnect on connection failure").

You can change the delay for reconnect attempts in the kitty.ini file if you're using the portable version. For example `ReconnectDelay=10` for a 10 second delay before attempting to reconnect. (By default the ini file has the line `#ReconnectDelay=5`, make sure to delete the `#` character from the beginning of the line for it to actually apply your changes.)

http://kitty.9bis.net/ (free / open source)

---

There are also a lot of other forks and alternatives that offer tabbed sessions, and an always-open session list on the side, if quick-opening of sessions is what you're looking for:

([MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), [MTPuTTY](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/), [SuperPuTTY](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty), etc).

And there are more with other features:

([ExtraPuTTY](http://www.extraputty.com/) has a slightly different auto-reconnect & optional [scripting with Lua](http://www.extraputty.com/features/lua.html), [RuTTY](https://sourceforge.net/p/rutty/wiki/Home/) has basic scripting--also included in [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) and [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) can open tabs with other sessions like Windows Command prompt / cmd, [Bitvise SSH Client](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download) has a nice interface, etc)

---

*I was messing around with [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) some more and it has a nice way to reconnect, you just press R. I can semi-automate it with the built-in macro tools too. And the MultiExec feature is cool cuz if I have multiple PuTTY tabs open, I can send commands to all of them at the same time (including restarting the session).*

*It seems to have a hard time saving session settings though. I often have to manually pick the COM port when I launch a saved session, unless the COM port is already active before I open MobaXterm (and the setting hasn't been lost already).*

Comment: Thank you for the help! This isn't really an ongoing issue obviously but take an upvote anyway for the nostalgia trip you just gave me. I totally forgot about asking this question! 

If I remember right I have tried it out before in the past. I'll have to go check out KiTTY again.